# In Visual Studio Code, how do I load my python code to a read-print-eval loop?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am teaching a class that uses VScode.

I am used to teaching using IDLE, and it is very nice for the students to be able to call their defined functions and run snippets of code in a python terminal, for debugging purposes.

In VScode, they I have been unable to do the same in a satisfactory way.

Option1: I can select all code, right click and run selection/line on terminal. This works for small snippets, but I cannot do it for the whole file (even after selecting the whole file with ctrl-A). On linux, this works, but on windows, it does not, unfortunately (and my students use windows)

Option2: I can use the debug console. This requires adding a breakpoint in one of the last lines of the file, and does not offer tab completion. It works, but is less convenient than IDLE.

Option 3: I can also add the commands to run to the bottom of the file (which is a least preferred alternative, given that is forgoes the interativity of the read-print-eval loop).

Is there any better solution? Installing a VScode extension would not be a problem.

Comment: You can use [Code-Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. Its an easy one click.

Comment: I have not yet been able to make the code runner extension run as desired: That is, to load the file, and open a python terminal that allows the students to run any of the defined functions with the arguments of their choosing

Comment: If they need to be able to input their own arguments then you can launch a terminal window inside of VSCode by using Ctrl+`.

Comment: That is also an alternative, but afaik they would need to open python on that terminal and then import the file they are working with. Is this correct? If so, can we find an easier solution? (the more I can make it easy, the better, given that they already have difficulties with coding itself)

Comment: If you have them open the python file in VSCode using the File->Open File command and then using my above solution. the terminal will automatically use the python interpreter. If I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I just tested and, in here, it unfortunately did not open python, just a terminal (I was unable to run with ctrl+`, but it ran with ctrl-'

Comment: However, even if it did run the python interpreter, it would not import the current file in any way, would it?

Comment: It opens the terminal yes. To actually execute the code you would need to type "python file.py" in the terminal window.

Comment: I understand. I wonder if there is some extension that auto-opens python and auto-imports the file (as opposed to just running it)

Comment: Ctrl-A selecting all code in a file should work with `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`. Please file an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues and include a code sample where this isn't working.

Comment: You should consider using PyCharm in future classes. JetBrains has a free educational version with all the features from the paid professional version. I believe it has these features out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Code is just a text editor like your traditional notepad. to run and debug any kind program you need to install the particular extension for the programming language.

In your case you are using python so you need to install the extension of it. the best one is the "Python" which is developed by microsoft itself. go to your extensions manager and install this extension. right click and click "run python file in terminal" and you are all set.

this will run exactly as they run from the idle(which is default IDE provided by python itself) you can enter the arguments from the console itself. according to me this is the best way to run and debug python programs in VScode.

another way is that VScode shows which python version is installed on your computer on the left bottom side, click on it and the programs will use this interpreter.

out of all the ways listed here and many others, the best method is to run the program in the terminal which is the recommend by python itself and many other programmers.

this method is very simple. what you have to do is open up your command prompt and type the path where python.exe is installed and the type the path of the your program as the argument and press enter. you are done !

ex : C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Username\Desktop\my_python_script.py
You can also pass your arguments of your program in the command prompt itself.
if you do not want to type all this and then just use the solution mentioned above.
hope that your query is solved.

regards